# How do I match one vectors index positions to a different vectors index positions?

Tags: r, sorting

I have two vectors with different values. I have sorted the second vector and need to rearrange the first vector so that it matches the index positions of the second vector. For example if vector B has values 3, 5, 1, 2 rearranged to 1,2,3,5, I need to sort vector A so that the index positions are the same as the positions of vector B rearranged. I've tried:

```
>sort(VectorB)
>match(c[VectorA], c[sort(VectorB)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `VectorA[order(VectorB)]`. To understand this issue, try

```
sig <- order(VectorB)
VectorB[sig]
VectorA[sig]
```

Comment: I tried using that code but it doesn't seem to order my first vector correctly. I need to sort VectorA in the order of VectorB increasing if that makes any sense.

Comment: You were completely right! I was using [order(sort(VectorB))] which seemed to mess it up. Sorry for my ineptitude.